# How to convert string in URI

Tags: voip, opensips

I setup OpenSips 2.3 proxy server, so any call come on server, my script grabs sip URI from DB, and forward call to that uri. When I get value I used AVP to get value and save it in $avp(didnumber), if I use rewrite with manually specifying uri it is working, but when I grab this value from DB and than assign it, it is not working in rewriteuri() method.

```
$ru = "sip:"+$avp(didnumber)
```

if I write

```
rewriteuri("[$ru]")
```

it throws following error

```
ERROR:core:parse_sip_msg_uri: bad uri <[$ru>
ERROR:tm:new_t: uri invalid
ERROR:tm:t_newtran: new_t failed
```

I think this method does not accept normal variable so I added quotation to make it string variable, now it shows fine on log but seem I have to convert variable using AVP or transformation, I tried many syntaxes but still could not do it. Please suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`rewrite_uri()` has been deprecated in favour of simply using `$ru`. Your R-URI already gets completely rewritten by this statement:

```
$ru = "sip:" + $avp(didnumber);
```

However, note that the above is incorrect, since you do not supply a "hostport" part to the uri, according to the SIP RFC 3261:

```
SIP-URI          =  "sip:" [ userinfo ] hostport
                    uri-parameters [ headers ]
```

The parser will likely report an error. There are two fixes for this:

- either only rewrite the R-URI "userinfo" part, like so:

  ```
  $rU = $avp(didnumber);
  ```
- supply a destination hostname:

  ```
  $ru = "sip:" + $avp(didnumber) + "@" + $var(destination);
  ```

Following from here, you can just `t_relay()` using your new R-URI.

**EDIT:** the OpenSIPS URI parser will actually tolerate a URI such as "sip:44776772882", but it will interpret the DID as a hostname, so the errors may start appearing later, should the script writer attempt to relay the message to the invalid "44776772882" hostname.

Comment: Thanks Liviu Chircu, I got your point thanks for brief explaination, but I have whole URI in string format, now searching for something that can transform my variable in the host, port, the user. As my DB has 111111@domain.com:5060 and these are million numbers.

Comment: `$var(did) = $(var(input){s.select,0,@});`

`$var(host) = $(var(input){s.select,1,@}{s.select,0,:});`